# how to select option 2 input field for show value from database

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql, html-select

The first option is always default selected if no-one else is, and.... for modal option try using selected="selected" instead of SELECTED

```
<select class="form-control" name="kategori" id="kategori"  value="NULL">
                    <?php
                        if(isset($pilihan_kategori)){                               
                            foreach ($pilihan_kategori as $kat) {
                                if($kat['kode_kategori'] == $hasil['kode_kategori']){
                    ?>
                        <option selected="selected" name="kategori" id="kategori" value="<?php echo $kat['kode_kategori'];?>"><?php echo $kat['nama_kategori'];?></option>
                    <?php
                                }else{
                    ?>
                        <option name="kategori" id="kategori" value="<?php echo $kat['kode_kategori'];?>"><?php echo $kat['nama_kategori'];?></option>
                    <?php
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

Comment: `<select multiple class="form-control" name="kategori" id="kategori"  value="NULL">`?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is a statement or a request ;-) but I have cleaned up your code a little so that you no longer need to open and close PHP consistently:

```
<?php
if(isset($pilihan_kategori)){

    echo '<select class="form-control" name="kategori" id="kategori"  value="NULL">';

    foreach ($pilihan_kategori as $kat) {
        $selected = ($kat['kode_kategori'] == $hasil['kode_kategori']) ? " selected='selected'" : "";

        echo "<option {$selected} name='kategori' id='kategori' value=" . $kat['kode_kategori'] . ">" . $kat['nama_kategori'] . "</option>";
    }

    echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

I hope this helps at all.